# C++11 standard ref for not initializing rvalue reference with lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider the following C++11 code:

```
int& f();

int&& i = f();
```

This produces an error:

```
cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’
```

I understand why, but I'm trying to justify it from the language in the standard.

Paraphrasing C++11 N3485 8.5.3.5:

> A reference to int is initialized by an expression of type int as follows: (yes)
>
> If the reference is an rvalue reference: (yes)
>
> If the initializer expression: (yes)
>
> 1. is an xvalue, class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue (no?), or
> 2. has class type [snip] (no)

Is it the case that neither of these two points apply?  So we should just assume it is ill-formed because neither do?

How can you determine from the standard that you can't initialize an rvalue reference to int with an lvalue of type int?

Comment: This is why `std::move` exists.

Comment: I haven't taken a close look at that part of the Standard, but wouldn't _function lvalue_ be a variable that refers to a function (rather than call the function), i.e. `f` rather than `f()`?

Comment: @chris: Sort of yes, `std::move` returns an rvalue reference, which when called as a postfix function call expression is an xvalue expression.

Comment: @jogojapan:  Yes, I think a function lvalue is an lvalue expression of function type - not a postfix function call expression.

Comment: Well then, since the initializer expression isn't an xvalue, prvalue or function lvalue, the section you quoted doesn't apply, right? As far as I understand, the following section ("Otherwise....") would have to be applied, and in order to answer your question we have to work out why that can't be done. According to what it says there, it's related to the rules for "non-reference copy initialization".

Comment: @jogojapan: Oh the last sentence of the last "Otherwise" paragraph in 8.5.3 says essentially "If the reference is an rvalue reference, the initializer expression shall not be an lvalue".  I think that might be it, but the part before about creating a temporary is confusing.

Comment: @user1131467 Yes, true! Unfortunately that applies only when the initializer type and the reference type are _reference-related_, which they are in your example, but not in general. I think for a general answer, we need to find something in the section on "non-reference copy initialization" that says it does not apply in cases like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed the last bullet of that article (8.5.3p5), that states:

> If T1 is reference-related to T2 and the reference is an rvalue
>   reference, the initializer expression shall not be an lvalue.

Comment: What if `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`?

Comment: @jogojapan: Look at the examples immediately after that.  If they are not reference-related, than it will bind ???  so `int x;` `int&& y = x;` error, `double&& y = x;` is ok.

Comment: @user1131467 I just think that should be part of the answer. In other words, rvalue references can be initialized from lvalue references, but only if they differ in type. In this case, a temporary will be created, and the next question would be about the life time of that.

Comment: @jogojapan: IUC then a temporary int is created and that is bound like in the very last example `double&& rrd3 = i3;`